# Create a patch with Tortoise SVN

Tags: tortoisesvn

I'm new on Tortoise SVN so maybe this question could seem silly...
Is there a way to create a "real" patch with Tortoise SVN?

I mean, I'd wish to export only latest files, so I can upload only them, instead of uploading everything every time.

How can I do that?

Comment: do you mean uploading the changes to the repository? or do you mean you want a patch file that you could send to another developer?

Comment: no no, i just want to export only the latest modified files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i found how can i do that:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/subversion-export-changed-files-cli/

Answer (score 1):

In TortoiseSVN, follow these steps

1. Context menu -> Show log
2. Select 2 revisions (using Ctrl+Click)
3. Right click -> Compare revisions
4. TortoiseSVN will display all related files for these 2 revisions
5. Select the files you want, right click -> Export selection to

Answer (score 0):

To create a patch file, right-click on the versioned folder, go the TortoiseSVN context menu and select "Create patch"